# Fail to execute SQL command asynchronously

Tags: sql-server

I want to invoke a SQL command `INSERT INTO` for 3,000,000 times to insert 3,000,000 records via ADO.

Other than the `BULK INSERT` command, I also want to utilize the ADO.Command object to execute the SQL command asynchronously.

So I do as follows:

```cpp
  CString strSQLChange;

  _ConnectionPtr pConnection = NULL;
  _CommandPtr pCmdChange = NULL;

  // Open connection.
  pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
  pConnection->Open (strCnn, "", "", adConnectUnspecified);

  // Create command object.
  pCmdChange.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
  pCmdChange->ActiveConnection = pConnection;


  for (UINT uIndex = 0; uIndex < 3000000, uIndex ++)
  {
     strSQLChange.Format(_T("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (%u, %u, %u);"), uIndex, uIndex *2, uIndex *3); 
     pCmdChange->CommandText = _bstr_t(strSQLChange);
     pCmdChange->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText | adAsyncExecute | adExecuteNoRecords);
  }
```

The first execution is OK. But the second one will cause the following error

> Operation cannot be performed while connecting asynchronously

Does that means the ADO command object cannot execute the SQL command asynchronously?

I am also thinking about using `BULK INSERT` command, but since there are multiple tables, I also need to execute `BULK INSERT` command multiple times. It is better to execute them asynchronously so executing SQL commands asynchronously is also a solution I need to seek.

Answer (score 2):

You need create a separate pCmdChange object for each `INSERT`:

```
for (UINT uIndex = 0; uIndex < 3000000, uIndex ++)
{
     // Create command object.
     pCmdChange.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Command));
     pCmdChange->ActiveConnection = pConnection;
     pCmdChange->CommandText = strSQLChange;

     pCmdChange->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText | adAsyncExecute | adExecuteNoRecords);
}
```

Keep in mind that your server probably won't like 3,000,000 near-concurrenct commands. You may run into SQL server dead-locks and or other connectivity issues.